# Mysterious nonetype appearing

Tags: python, function, nonetype

python 3.7

Hello.
I know that `None` is the result of nothing being returned, however I can't understand why I am getting `None` returned at the end of this code.  I can't see anything left unfinished.

```
def test(a, b):
    if a == True and b == True:
        return False
    elif a == True or b == True:
        return True
    elif a == False and b == False:
        return False
    else:
        print("error... :(")

print(test(True, True))
print(test(True, False))
print(test(False, True))
print(test(False, False))
print(test(None, False))
```

When I run this code I get:

```
False
True
True
False
error... :(
None
```

I have also tried altering the else: statement to actually return the printed object hoping that my code was simply asking for a redundent return, but the output is the same.

```
    else:
        error = print("error... :(")
    return error
```

Can anyone shed some light on where the `None` is coming from?

Comment: If you reach the end of a function without hitting a `return` then your function returns `None`. Also, `print` returns `None`. So both in both versions, your function returns `None` in that particular case. If you want it to return something different, figure out what and `return` it.

Comment: The final `else` doesn't return anything, therefore it returns `None`.

Comment: Thank you Mike Scotty.  I was sure someone else had asked this question before but couldn't find it.  Sorry for the double up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else statement prints out the line "error... :(", however you also attempt to print out the results of the function. Either let the function handle printing and return nothing (remove print statements from main body), or have the function return the string you want to print instead of printing it from the function (seen below).

```
def test(a, b):
if a == True and b == True:
    return False
elif a == True or b == True:
    return True
elif a == False and b == False:
    return False
else:
    return "error... :("

print(test(True, True))
print(test(True, False))
print(test(False, True))
print(test(False, False))
print(test(None, False))
```

Comment: Thank you.  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: If this solution works, please make sure to accept it as the answer!

Comment: thanks for the tip.  very new to this community and I appreciate the help :)